# PDOException::("could not find driver") on Laravel migration. PHP version is 7.3.7. Extension is uncommented in php.ini. Not sure what else to do

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here are a few facts:

I'm using MySQL and can insert, update, delete and select from the database just fine, however, when I try to migrate, I get this error -

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lol and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

When I `phpinfo();`, it says that my project uses PHP 7.3.7 and my `php.ini` file is located in `C:\MAMP\conf\php7.3.7\php.ini`

When I type `php --ini` in the command line I get `Loaded Configuration File: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.3.7\php.ini`

These 3 lines in the php.ini file are uncommented

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

In database.php laravel file MySQL is set as default:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

Migrations worked last time I used them but now I'm getting this error. Any ideas on how to fix it?

`get_loaded_extensions()` returns this:

```
array:45 [▼
  0 => "Core"
  1 => "bcmath"
  2 => "calendar"
  3 => "com_dotnet"
  4 => "ctype"
  5 => "date"
  6 => "filter"
  7 => "hash"
  8 => "iconv"
  9 => "json"
  10 => "SPL"
  11 => "odbc"
  12 => "pcre"
  13 => "Reflection"
  14 => "session"
  15 => "sockets"
  16 => "standard"
  17 => "mysqlnd"
  18 => "tokenizer"
  19 => "zip"
  20 => "zlib"
  21 => "libxml"
  22 => "dom"
  23 => "PDO"
  24 => "bz2"
  25 => "SimpleXML"
  26 => "soap"
  27 => "xml"
  28 => "wddx"
  29 => "xmlreader"
  30 => "xmlwriter"
  31 => "apache2handler"
  32 => "mysqli"
  33 => "openssl"
  34 => "gd"
  35 => "gettext"
  36 => "mbstring"
  37 => "exif"
  38 => "pdo_sqlite"
  39 => "sqlite3"
  40 => "curl"
  41 => "Phar"
  42 => "imagick"
  43 => "pdo_mysql"
  44 => "fileinfo"
]
```

Comment: Do you have different php.ini files for the webserver and the cli by any chance?

Comment: You might try to run a PHP script through your webserver and output [get_loaded_extensions()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) to confirm if the PDO driver is being loaded when the webserver runs PHP.

Comment: @PtrTon I thought that if phpinfo() and php --ini show the same php.ini file, that means they're using the same php.ini. Is that how it goes?

Comment: @BillKarwin I've added what get_loaded_extensions() return in my question.

Comment: Did you run that from the CLI, or from a page loaded by the webserver? Remember that any time you edit php.ini, you must restart your webserver for the changes to take effect. Whereas they will take effect immediately in the CLI.

Comment: I think you need the mysqlnd driver in addition to the MySQL PDO extension. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Comment: @BillKarwin I ran that from a page loaded by the webserver. I also restart the server every time I make any changes to the php.ini.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I'm out of ideas. Good luck.